# Bash: kill process and all subprocesses without using group id

Tags: bash, process

I have a bash script which is spawning child processes, which spawn grandchild and great grandchild processes.

I want to kill a particular child, and all it's decedents.

Here are some solutions I've tried that don't work for me:

1. Killing via group id. The child may have sibling processes with the same group id I do not want to kill.
2. Using `kill $childpid`. This is not killing all grandchildren and great grandchildren processes
3. Using `kill -9 $childpid`. This leads to text output in terminal that I ran the script from, which is not ideal, even if the script and the kill command both have their stdout and stderr routed to a different file
4. Using `pkill -P $childpid`. This seems to do what I want at first, but the child process exits with exit code zero. The parent process needs to know its child was killed prematurely, so I need it to exit with a code other than 0

So **TL;DR, I need a way to kill a process and all descendent processes, without killing siblings with the same group id, without output printed in the terminal, and with a non-zero exit code.**

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: There is a [hack](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/588275/111181) of using a different process group id for the job. Does that help? Maybe using a different signal and/or trapping the signal properly in child process is needed.